# Angular2 Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, observable, observers

I am new to observable and implementing common angular2 service to handle API calls and to wrap auth token with request.

For that I am using https://gist.github.com/chandermani/9166abe6e6608a31f471

Now for handling 401 error I have changed it little bit.

```
private _request(method: RequestMethod, url: string, body?: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Rx.Observable<Response> {
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions(Object.assign({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        body: body
    }, options));

    if (!requestOptions.headers) {
        requestOptions.headers = new Headers();
    }

    requestOptions.headers.set('Authorization', this._buildAuthHeader());

    return Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
        this.process.next(Action.QueryStart);
        this._http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
            .map(res => res.json())
            .finally(() => {
                this.process.next(Action.QueryStop);
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    this.renewToken().subscribe((res) => { }, (err) => { }, () => {
                        requestOptions.headers.set('Authorization', this._buildAuthHeader());
                        this._http.request(new Request(requestOptions))
                            .map(res => res.json())
                            .subscribe(
                            (res) => {
                                observer.next(res);
                                observer.complete();
                            },
                            (err) => {
                            },
                            () => {

                            });
                    });
                } else {
                    observer.next();
                    observer.complete();
                    return Rx.Observable.timer(1);
                }
            })
            .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                observer.next(res);
                observer.complete();
            },
            (err) => {
                switch (err.status) {
                    case 401:
                        // intercept 401
                        this.authFailed.next(err);
                        observer.error(err);
                        break;
                    default:
                        observer.error(err);
                        break;
                }
            });
    });
}
```

Which works fine as expected. On 401 it refreshes token and then execute API call and return result from API. But it gives error in console.

```
Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined
at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:48:1), <anonymous>:45:27)
at CatchSubscriber.error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:1921:1), <anonymous>:60:33)
at FinallySubscriber.Subscriber._error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:128:26)
at FinallySubscriber.Subscriber.error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:102:18)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:128:26)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:20:1), <anonymous>:102:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:1634:1), <anonymous>:88:34)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:759:1), <anonymous>:236:37)
at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/vendor.js:2622:1), <anonymous>:35:37)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:759:1), <anonymous>:235:42)
at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:759:1), <anonymous>:136:47)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/js/polyfills.js:759:1), <anonymous>:304:33)
```

Please help me with the problem or how to trace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it at the point of subscription like this.

```
observable$.subscribe(response => {
  //success
},
response => {
  //error
});
```

see:

- https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html#retrying-sequences
- [Can I catch certain errors before "subscribe()" in an RXJS observable in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666452/can-i-catch-certain-errors-before-subscribe-in-an-rxjs-observable-in-angular#36667203)